# logback.xml is evaluated before application.yml is

Tags: spring-boot

I'm building a web application using spring-boot 1.2.2.RELEASE.

I want to configure the logback output according to the value of the property "spring.profiles.active".

That property is defined in application.yml and lockback configuration is described in logback.xml.

But I found logback.xml is evaluated before application.yml is evaluated.

How can I start a SpringApplication reading application.yml before logback.xml?

Here is my Application.java.

```
/**
 * Application.java --
 */
package my.project;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).run(args);
    }

}
```

When I write the logback.xml in some bad format like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
aaa
```

Spring-boot reports an error which shows logback.xml is read in the constructor of SpringApplicationBuilder.

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.event.SaxEventRecorder@449b193b - XML_PARSING - Parsing fatal error on line 2 and column 1 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 1;
        [snip]
        at      at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
        at      at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
        at      at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:275)
        at      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:160)
        at      at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.createSpringApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:96)
        at      at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:84)
        at      at my.project.Application.main(Application.java:13)
        [snip]
```

On the other hand, when I put the application.yml in some bad format by adding tab character, Spring-boot reports an error which shows it is read in the method 'run'.

```
Caused by: while scanning for the next token
found character          '\t(TAB)' that cannot start any token. (Do not use \t(TAB) for indentation)
 in 'reader', line 1, column 1:
        [snip]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:126)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:285)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
        at my.project.Application.main(Application.java:13)
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I start a SpringApplication reading application.yml before logback.xml

You can't.

The Logback configuration is read very early so that logging is available for the rest of the initialisation process. There's then a second stage where Logback is reconfigured based on some of the configuration in `application.yml`.

Logging frameworks don't understand `application.yml` or Spring's Environment so certain properties are copied over the system properties which you can then reference in your Logback configuration. Those properties are `logging.file` and `logging.path` which are copied to `LOGGING_FILE` and `LOGGING_PATH` respectively. See the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration) for some more information.

There's also an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1788) to allow more of the logging configuration to be performed in `application.yml`.

Comment: Thank you.
I understand.

I'd like to find other way to configure logging according to active profiles.

Comment: It appears the properties files are read before logback.  An option would be to switch out the yaml for a properties file