# How to inject active spring profile into logback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-profiles

I'm using a spring boot project.

Environment:

```
ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.5
ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.5
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE
```

In my project I'm using properties with application.yml (application-dev.yml and application-production.yml)

Since the Logback Spring extension starts before Spring I'm not able to inject the spring.profiles.active into the logback.xml file.

This is a simpler version of my logback.xml file:

```
<configuration scan="true">

   <property name="LOG_PATH" value="/var/log/" />
   <property name="APP_NAME" value="xyz" />
   <property name="PROFILE" value="-${spring.profiles.active}" />
   <property name="CHARSET" value="utf-8" />
   <property name="PATTERN" value="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />

   <appender name="APP-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <file>${LOG_PATH}${APP_NAME}${PROFILE}.log</file>
      <encoder>
         <charset>${CHARSET}</charset>
         <Pattern>${PATTERN}</Pattern>
      </encoder>
   </appender>

   <logger name="a.b.c" level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="APP-FILE" />
   </logger>

   <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="APP-FILE"/>
   </root>
```

The PROFILE I'm looking for is the property **spring.profiles.active**.

My goal is to have a log file on directory **/var/log** the files **xyz-dev** or **xyz-production** but I getting **xyz-spring.profiles.active_IS_UNDEFINED.log** instead of course.

Approaches:

1 - Using a component like:

```
@Component
public class InitializationService implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

// inject spring profile active into logback.xml

}
```

is not working of course because the logback Spring extension starts before Spring Boot application.

2 - Using a property on the logback.xml like this

```
<file>${LOG_PATH}${APP_NAME}${PROFILE}.log</file>
```

The result is xyz-spring.profiles.active_IS_UNDEFINED.log

Comment: if PROFILE is a property with key-value for the active profile, it should work

Comment: The PROFILE I'm looking for is the property **spring.profiles.active** which is defined in application.yml or via command line.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a little late to answer, but I have successfully logged the Spring profile by renaming my "logback.xml" file to "logback-spring.xml", and accessed the profile like this (much) simplified version

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="ACTIVE_PROFILE" source="spring.profiles.active"/>

<appender name="GRAYLOG" class="com.github.pukkaone.gelf.logback.GelfAppender">

    <additionalField>environment=${ACTIVE_PROFILE}</additionalField>

</appender>

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="GRAYLOG" />
</root>
```

It seems that "logback-spring.xml" can pick up the profile information.

The specific [documentation is here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration).

Comment: It has worked perfectly for me but I didn't need to rename my logback.xml file. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

- Since you're using Spring Boot you can define `logging.file=blah.log`. See [official docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html).
- Or you can use vanilla Logback and pass a system variable: `-DLOG_FILE=blah.log`.

**Why you shouldn't use profiles:**

What you're trying to do is not what spring profiles were created for. They are needed to switch on/off beans to activate/deactivate behaviour during startup. *Profiles is not recommended practice in general* since what you test and what works in production is different (though sometimes there is no other choice). See *Caveats* section of [the original announcement](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/).

Another problem with your usage of profiles is that multiple profiles can be activated at the same time. Profiles were created to switch on/off small unrelated parts. E.g. `spring.profiles.active=cache-off,perf-monitoring-on` or something of that kind.

Having all that said you can still define a profile and set `logging.file=prod.log` property within that profile. That's still *very* bad and not how profiles should be used, but that's better.

Comment: "Profiles is not recommended practice in general since what you test and what works in production is different" 
In the Caveats section you quote, I don't read anything in this way.
It says rather : **The set of beans registered between two profiles should probably be more similar than different.** And that I agree with.
Generally, web applications must move through multiple environments (dev, integration, etc... until production) and each one has specificities (OS, url, database, etc...) , ignoring that is a bad practice.

Comment: @davidhxxx URLs, databases, etc should not be defined in profiles. Those need to be defined as system vars, env vars, in JNDI or in application-specific configuration files. Please also don't take just one piece out of the article, it also says: _Do not use profiles if a simpler approach can get the job done_

Comment: I don't take just one piece out of the article. **Do not use profiles if a simpler approach can get the job done** doesn't convey that URL, database information, etc... should not be in the profile. Besides, you say that  these information could be in application-specific configuration files.
But with Spring boot, profiles works also with application-specific configuration file than you can load when the server is launched or retrieved at runtime via a Property annotation. Profiles are not only Java code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant _external_ application-specific configuration files. If you want a comprehensive answer on why profiles is a bad choice to configure apps, you could create a question. I won't be able to provide detailed explanation in comments..

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did for my project. Inside your `logback.xml`

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

<property resource="application.properties"/>
```

Then you can use properties which are defined in your application.properties file. `${MY-PROPERTY}`
In my application.properties I have a property for the logfile's name.

This does not work with `application.yml => YAML` property file because the `yaml` file is interpreted after logback init.

Comment: In my project I'm using properties with application.yml (application-dev.yml and application-production.yml) ... so do you have other approach?

Comment: Well no, I tried and it seems you can't. Maybe switch back to a property file, but watch out if you have special characters (property file is not utf-8 friendly) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669049/logback-xml-is-evaluated-before-application-yml-is